# Cannot see jsdoc methods suggestion after transpile with rollup

Tags: sdk, babeljs, commonjs, rollupjs, iife

Currently we are export our sdk library using rollup js with cjs format to transpile with named exports.

rollup config file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  input: "src/index.js",
  output: [
    {
      // we only supports browser environment
      file: "build/bundles/bundle.cjs.js",
      format: "cjs",
      sourcemap: true,
      name: "client",
      exports: "named",
    },
    {
      file: "build/bundles/bundle.iife.js",
      format: "iife",
      name: "client",
    } 
  ],
  plugins: [
    globals(),

    babel({
      babelHelpers: "runtime",
      exclude: "node_modules/**", // Only transpile our source code
    }),
    resolve({
      browser: true,
      preferBuiltins: true,
    }),
    commonjs(),
    banner(copyright),
  ],
};
```

When transpilation done we get something like this:
[image]

Works perfectly but **after transpile** it doesn't show methods signature:
[image]

Expected result without transpile:
[image]

Anyone knows why after transpile our source code missing our jsdoc signature?
thanks.

Comment: did you find a solution for this yet?

Comment: @DysphoricUnicorn unfortunately not yet. If you find something please share.

Comment: apparently at least with idea based IDEs, the signatures can be used from the non transpiled code if you define a field called nextjs:main that points at the pre-transpiled code in your package.json. Not really a good solution imo but better than nothing. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26724